# Conservation of energy in transformers

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

How does energy remain conserved in a transformer if emf is increasing, or decreasing?
Does the current decreases to accomodate?
Does Ohm's law still hold here? Although we know, Ohm's law is not universal.

Comment: energy is conserved in every energy consuming process in this world

Comment: I dont ask whether it remains conserved or not, I asked, how does it remain conserved

Comment: Almost same: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230059/if-a-step-up-transformer-increases-voltage-then-how-current-can-be-decreased , and,  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230404/how-does-the-secondary-coil-of-a-transformer-affect-the-primary-coil-how-is-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about Ohm's law, you might be getting a little muddled in your thoughts (don't worry, I only know this because *I've* had my turn at being muddled before on this point!)

Ohm's law doesn't describe a transformer: Ohm's law *may* apply to whatever load you *connect to* the transformer; if so, then Ohm's law *combines* with the transformer law $V_P\, I_P = V_S\, I_S$ to yield the concept of [*reflected impedance* (as I talk about in the linked answer)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/73543/26076): a load with impedance $\mathcal{Z}$ connected across the transformer's secondary appears as the load $\left(\frac{N_S}{N_P}\right)^2\,\mathcal{Z}$ at the primary. This generalises to:

$$Z_P \approx \left(Z_{T1}^{-1}+\left(Z_{T2}+\left(\frac{N_S}{N_P}\right)^2\,\mathcal{Z}\right)^{-1}\right)^{-1}$$

in a real transformer, where $Z_{T1}$ and $Z_{T2}$ model the transformer's own ohmic losses and energy storage capacity.

The transformer equation itself can be thought of as either:

1. A statement of conservation of energy; OR
2. A statement that the same flux links the primary and secondary and the consequences of applying (a) Ampère's law to a flux loop threading both primary and secondary to get the current ratio from and (b) Faraday's law to flux time variation, to get the voltage ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) calls this the transformer equation:
$$\frac{V_P}{V_S} = \frac{I_S}{I_P}=\frac{N_\text{P}}{N_\text{S}}=\sqrt{\frac{L_P}{L_S}}$$
$P$ and $S$ denote primary and secondary, respectively. $V,I,N$ and $L$ are emf, current, winding number and inductance. Keeping this ratio constant assures that the power $P=V_SI_S=V_PI_P$ is the same on either side.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out long ago. But what I could figure out since long was that, wouldnt it violate our old pal Ohm's law?

Comment: @Rohit: No, this becomes a voltage to be considered. So if you plug a $10:1$ stepdown transformer into a $120VAC$ outlet, you have $12VAC$ at the output.  If you connect that across a $2\Omega$ resistor, you will draw $6 AAC$.  That will draw $0.6 AAC$ from the wall.  The back emf is then $120VAC$ and all is well.

Comment: @Rohit If you're concerned about how Ohm's law fits in to conservation of energy, please put that in your question.